# Webkit Transform not working in a Webkit Animation

Tags: google-chrome, css, animation, webkit

I made a simple animation that should rotate a div.

```
@-webkit-keyframes turn{   
    0% { -webkit-transform:(0deg); }  
    100% { -webkit-transform:(360deg); }
}
```

And I assigned it to the div.

```
#myDiv
{
    -webkit-animation-name:turn;
    -webkit-animation-duration:4s;
}
```

The animation is not working on Chrome, however when I use the same animation on firefox (adding -moz-) things work perfectly.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6S3C/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget transforming function. The correct syntax is:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
```

I've updated your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6S3C/1/).